# sed command results in unterminated address regex

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to search and replace a string with the sed command in linux but keep getting errors in STDERR such as

`sed: -e expression #1, char 53: unterminated address regex`

Here's what doing:

```
string="SOMEFILE.TXT SOMEFILE2.TXT SOMEFILE3.TXT"
path="/path/to/file/"
replace="TXT \] || \[ ${path}SOME"
formatted_string=`echo ${string} | sed -e "/TXT SOME/${replace}/g"`

if [ -e ${path}/${formatted_string} ]; then
```

The end goal is to have a formatted string to insert into the if command to look for one or more files if they exist.  The string with files can vary so that's why I'm  doing this. The above code works and it does find the files but I can't get rid of the error.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You'll do better with `fmtStr=$( echo "$string" | sed -e "s@TXT SOME@${replace}@g")` . Most importantly, note you were missing the `s` command at the front, and rather than try to escape `/` chars in your patterns, use `@` to avoid that hassle. Don't have time to debug it all, but update your Q if there are still problems. Good luck.

Comment: This code shouldn't work as expected because `||` are literal and not syntactical so can't be used as `||` control operator

Answer (score 1):

The right way

```
array=( "SOMEFILE.TXT" "SOMEFILE2.TXT" "SOMEFILE3.TXT")
path_to_file="/path/to/file/"

file_exist=
for filename in "@{array[@]}"; do
    if [ -e "${path_to_file}/${filename}" ]; then
        file_exist=1
    fi
done

if [ -n "${file_exist:+X}" ]; then
...
```

or shorter (one-liner)

```
shopt -s extglob
if [ -e "/file/to/path/"@("SOMEFILE.TXT"|"SOMEFILE2.TXT"|"SOMEFILE3.TXT") ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code

```
string="SOMEFILE.TXT SOMEFILE2.TXT SOMEFILE3.TXT"
path="\/path\/to\/file\/"
replace="TXT \] || \[ ${path}SOME"
formatted_string=`echo ${string} | sed -e "s/TXT SOME/${replace}/g"`

echo $formatted_string
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need is something like:

```
if ls /path/to/file/SOMEFILE*.TXT >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    at least one file exists so do whatever...
fi
```

or if you want to do something with the list of files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(/path/to/file/SOMEFILE*.TXT)
if [ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    at least one file exists so do whatever...
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the help!  I ended up omitting the sed command altogether and found a more practical solution:

```
string="/path/to/file/SOMEFILE*.TXT"
files=$(ls ${string} 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ **"$files" != "0"** ]; then
```

This does what I need and seems easier to read than what I was trying to do earlier.